# Adjust colors selected item in a TListview AFTER processing an item in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, tlistview

after spending a lot of time with

'''

```
procedure Tf100.lvListCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;    // default was clBlack
end;

procedure Tf100.lvListCustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;    // Default was clBlack;
end;
```

'''

I was able to change the color of the items in the listview. However, what I really want is:

1. Display all the items in the listview in black (done, okay)
2. loop through all the items programmatically and select 1 item at the time (done, okay) BUT
   make the font color RED    (the color of the selected item).
3. Read the caption of the item (a filename) and process that filename (done, okay)
4. If processing is done succesful, make the current item GREEN, if not succesful leave it red.
5. Select the next item in the list until the end of the list (done, okay).

Hope this makes sense. Summarized it means: how to change the color of a TListItem depending on the result of a certain function. I even don't know in what event I should call this function (in an event of the listview?).

For now, I have this:

```
iIndex := 0;
repeat

    pbProgress.Position := iIndex + 1;

    try
       lvList.SetFocus;                  // The color should become clRED
       lvList.ItemIndex := iIndex;
       lvList.Items[iIndex].Selected := true;
       lvList.Selected.MakeVisible(True);

       sFile := txtFolder.text + '\' + lvList.Items[iIndex].Caption;
       DisplayPicture(sFile);
       application.processmessages ;
       txtCurrent.Text := Format('%D of %D',[iIndex + 1, iMax]);
       bOke := ProcessFile(sFile);

       if (bOke) then begin
           // Current index color should become clGREEN but I don't know how
       end;

    except
        on E:Exception do begin
           bOke := False;
           msgbox(Format('Error at index %d',[iIndex]),'ooops',acError,[mbOk],['Press']);
        end;
    end;

    if (bOke) then
        Inc(FGood)
    else
        Inc(FWrong);

    UpdateStats(Self);

    Inc(iIndex);

until (iIndex = iMax);
```

Hope someone is able to answer my question.
Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Lazarus installed, so the following is done with Delphi. I'm 99.9% sure it works for you too.

You have already seen how you can define the color of an item, in the `OnCustomDrawItem()` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` events.

Here it is important to understand that the `TListView` does not save that color setting anywhere. If you think about scrolling the list up and down, the list view calls the `OnCustomDrawItem()` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` events for each item as they need to be drawn. The state of an item might have changed since it was previously displayed.

Therefore you need to save the result of your file processing somewhere, so that you can tell the list view what color to use for each item, in the `OnCustomDrawItem()` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` events.

I suggest you create a data structure, a simple class that holds the filename and the result of the processing. Then, when you add the files to the list view for display, you also add a reference to each of your file objects to the list view.

First some type and variable declarations

```
type
  // enum for the different processing states
  TProcessEnum = (NotDone, Processing, DoneSucceeded, DoneFailed);
  // class for holding file names and process state
  TMyFileData = class
    FileName: string;
    ProcessState: TProcessEnum;
  end;
  // Array type for file data
  TMyFileDataArray = array of TMyFileData;

const
  // string representation for process states
  ProcessStates: array of string = ['Not done', 'Processing', 'Succeeded', 'Failed'];

var
  // data array
  MyFileDataArray: TMyFileDataArray;
```

Then create some demo data

```
procedure TForm21.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(MyFileDataArray, 9);

  for i := 0 to Length(MyFileDataArray)-1 do
  begin
    MyFileDataArray[i] := TMyFileData.Create;
    MyFileDataArray[i].FileName := 'c:\tmp\example'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt';
    MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState := NotDone;
  end;
end;
```

Then add file names and data references to LV Item and process state to LV sub item. The data reference is the second argument to `AddItem()` and it can be accessed later in the `OnCustomDrawItem()` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` events using `Item.Data`

```
procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(MyFileDataArray)-1 do
  begin
    ListView1.AddItem(MyFileDataArray[i].FileName, MyFileDataArray[i]);
    ListView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(ProcessStates[ord(MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState)]);
  end;
end;
```

And run the processing of all files

```
procedure TForm21.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(MyFileDataArray)-1 do
  begin
    MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState := processing;
    ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[0] := ProcessStates[ord(MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState)];
    ListView1.Repaint;  // force a visual update

    sleep(500); // simulate processing delay 

    MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState := TProcessEnum(random(2) + 2);
    ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[0] := ProcessStates[ord(MyFileDataArray[i].ProcessState)];
    ListView1.Repaint;  // force a visual update
  end;
end;
```

Helper function to translate ProcessState to color

```
function TForm21.ItemColor(ProcessState: TProcessEnum): TColor;
begin
  case ProcessState of
    DoneSucceeded: Result := clGreen;
    Processing,
    DoneFailed: Result := clRed;
  else
    Result := clBlack;
  end;
end;
```

Both `OnCustomDrawItem()` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` have the following line only

```
Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := ItemColor(TMyFileData(Item.Data).ProcessState);
```

Note though, that you might want to modify the background or font colors further depending on the `State: TCustomDrawState` value.

Comment: Dear Tom,

many, MANY thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I needed.
You rock. Best regards, Martin

Comment: You are welcome @Martin, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and perhaps also [tour] for a general overview